# ETag generation with content type suffix in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

My requirement is this: in an ASP.NET Core Web API action, return a response with ETag in this format: `<guid>_json` where `json` is the type of the content returned.

This is to ensure that if the action returned something else in the future and the client is also expecting that, then this cached content (based on the old ETag) will be discarded.

Now, I only return a C# object in my actions, how would I know what formatter in ASP.NET Core would use to serialize this object?

In an older ASP.NET Framework project, we would do something like this to figure that out:

```
var configuration = request.GetConfiguration();
var negotiator = (IContentNegotiator)configuration.Services.GetService(typeof(IContentNegotiator));
var result = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof(MyType), request, configuration.Formatters);
var returnContentType = result.MediaType;
```

What is the equivalent of this in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Seems you are looking for [`content negotiation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#content-negotiation-2) feature in asp.net core. You could [`have a look in this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#content-negotiation-2)

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that document, note that while it describes how Core framework handles content negotiation, it doesn't really give an idea on how to figure out in format Core will eventually stream the data to the client - is it JSON, XML, etc. 

The Framework code I shared above will tell me how to figure that.